# Is there a way of lazy initializing a static sub-object of a class?

Tags: c++, static-members, lazy-initialization

Is there a way of initializing a static class member after main() has started ?

Comment: What do you mean by *static sub-object*? Do you mean *static member*?

Comment: Yes a static member that is an object of an embedded class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do that is to replace the static member data which static member function.

Say you've this class:

```
class A
{
   static B static_b; //static member data
};

//.cpp
B A::static_b; //definition (required)
```

So instead of that you can define your class as:

```
class A
{
   static B static_b()  //static member function!
   {
       static B b;
       return b;
   }
};
```

Note that it is not thread-safe, but you can make it thread-safe as well.

Comment: That seems to be OK specially because the object b will be destroyed automatically at the end of main(). Isn't that very similar to a singleton ?

Comment: @user1042389: It is *similar* to singleton, in a way that you access the data which you want to use, by calling a *static* function. But the class `A` itself is not a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pointer for this object:

```
class SomeClass{
public:
    static SomeOtherClass* p;
};

SomeOtherClass* SomeClass::p;    

void main(){
    SomeClass::p = new SomeOtherClass();
}
```

Comment: But this allocation will have to be destroyed manually. I would like to avoid this.